# Should I use Android Instrumentation to write unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I have read some articles about unit testing in Android including the official documentations and wrote some demos, it is complicated and slow because it must run on a device or emulator. Should I continue using it or find another option?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a good test should run on the target device. Thats why my answer is: yes you should continue using it. If you test on an emulator or something like that there could be some little differences that would cause some different behaviour than on the real device (espacially if you use some hardware components).
If you use a real device there is also the side benefit that the test runs faster than on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

My alternative looks like this:

I have refactored my android app into

- app (gui using the libs),
- android-independant-lib (service-interfaces, dto-s, businesslogic without database bindings)
- android-dependent-lib (android specific implementation of the of the service-interfaces and database binding)

for the android-independant-lib i have created "normal" junit-tests

for the android-specific parts i currently have no automatted tests.

Comment: It seems interesting, but sometimes we should test the UI or lifecycle of components.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).

> Robolectric is a unit test framework that de-fangs the Android SDK jar so you can test-drive the development of your Android app. Tests run inside the JVM on your workstation in seconds.

It is not complete yet (e.g. Support Library Action Bar is not supported) but it will save you a lot of time anyway. Besides you can add what's missing by developing `shadows` yourself.

Comment: The project is hosted at https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric, not where you pointed. What's deprecated is some gradle plugin written by one of the authors of Robolectric, but not Robolectric itself.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I deleted my original wrong comment about the [depricated roboelectric-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin). Is there any non-depricated roboelectric-gradle-plugin?

Comment: On maven, there is no such thing as a Robolectric plugin. Robolectric is a library used to write JUnit tests, which are executed by plugins such as surefire. I guess it is similar on Gradle.